# Displaying images with Javascript based on user input

Tags: javascript, django, image

I have been trying to display image with the following code. The user input is intended to be compared to bring up the right picture.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var defaultimg = document.getElementById('image1');
defaultimg.src = pictureImage;
var pictureImage = "images/unknown.png";
if({{messages.get.message}} == "Mewtwo"){   
var imgobject = document.getElementById('image1');
imgobject.src = pictureImage;
pictureImage = "images/150.png";
}
if({{messages.get.message}} == "Charmeleon"){   
var imgobject2 = document.getElementById('image1');
imgobject2.src = pictureImage;
pictureImage = "images/005.png";
}

if({{messages.get.message}} == "Warturtle"){    
var imgobject3 = document.getElementById('image1');
imgobject3.src = pictureImage;
pictureImage = "images/008.png";
}


)}
```

to the following piece of html

```
<img id="image1" alt="Pokemon" width="88" height="75">&ensp;
```

At the moment it only displays an empty box.

Can someone offer advice on whether this approach can be fixed to display the images? Thanks for the time and help.

Comment: Why do you have a python tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's probably a reference loop:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     var defaultimg = document.getElementById('image1'); 
     // defaultimg now contains image1
     // using jQuery and getElementbyId together is weired

     defaultimg.src = pictureImage;  
     // pictureImage is not assigned, so the url is empty
     // prob. cause for empty block?

     var pictureImage = "images/unknown.png"; 
     // ok, now we assign an url 

     if({{messages.get.message}} == "Mewtwo"){   
     // is that path correct?

       var imgobject = document.getElementById('image1'); 
       // copy of the empty image from above

       imgobject.src = pictureImage;       
       // we assign an url

       pictureImage = "images/150.png";    
       // new url on pictureImage, unused so far.
     }
  ...
```

if none of the conditions like `if({{messages.get.message}} == "Mewtwo"){`
is true, it must show nothing due to `defaultimg.src = pictureImage;`  with unassigned pictureImage variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to state with which kind of template engine or the like you work, as "{{messages.get.message}}" wouldn't help you much in vanilla js (though it would be syntactically well formed)

Tip for debugging:

debugger;

in js code starts up the debugger in chrome/firefox(+firebug)/...

otherwise you can also use the console commands, e.g.
console.debug("if 1") 
to find out what is happening

also have a look at console output in general, there should be no warnings or errors.

Next:
You're trying to use the probably global (because of missing "var" in front) variable "pictureImage" before you define it. Javascript is run from start to end, from left to right (let's just assume it's that way for easier understanding), top to bottom.

So you try to set the src of an image to something which is undefined at that point, and later on define that variable. There is no such thing as pointers to non-object types in javascript (which string *constants* are)

To fix your problem you'll probably have to swap some lines in your code, so the used variable gets set, and THEN is used, not the other way around.

Comment: Hello, I have tried swapping the variables around so it is used, yet there is no images displaying. Could this just be an issue with the code I have?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want to say with "Could this just be an issue with the code I have?". What else should it be? And aren't you here to get help on that? That's also why I've pointed out how to debug javascript code. If you're too lazy to read, at least: https://www.google.at/search?q=console.debug

Comment: Have you checked how the code the client gets delivered looks like? As you have at least a couple of problems with your javascript, you might want to update your post with the actual javascript which gets delivered to the client(probably browser).